# i want to make one object by matching id with other object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ecmascript-6

[image]I have to objects
1: categories
2: Categories count

both have _id in it. I have to match the ID's of both object and make it one object and also avoid null.
I tried making it via the map but the results are irrelevant.

```
"count": [
            {
                "_id": "63d18ade150a09494a7922ba",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a792298",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": null,
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229a",
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a792299",
                "count": 2
            }
        ],

"categories": [
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a792298",
                "name": "Agriculter & Food",
                "enabled": false,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a792299",
                "name": "Animals & Pets",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229a",
                "name": "Babies & Kids",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229b",
                "name": "Commercial & Equipment & Tools",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229e",
                "name": "Health & Beauty",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229f",
                "name": "Home, Furniture & Appliances",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a0",
                "name": "Jobs",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a1",
                "name": "Mobile Phones & Tablets",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a2",
                "name": "Property",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a3",
                "name": "Repair & Construction",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a4",
                "name": "Services",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a5",
                "name": "Sports, Arts & Outdoors",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a7922a6",
                "name": "Vehicles",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0,
                "mobile_image": "imgName-1675366698075.png",
                "image": "imgName-1675367702205.png"
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229c",
                "name": "Electronics",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63d18ab8150a09494a79229d",
                "name": "Faishon",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "createdDate": "2023-03-13T15:29:11.104Z",
                "_id": "63ed51eb047ccbe75d91a982",
                "name": "Example",
                "enabled": true,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "image": "",
                "mobile_image": "",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
```

This is my json response but they are in different objects i want to make it one object with then name and count

I tried to make it via this map

```
 const result = categorycount.map(obj1 => {
                                const matchingObj2 = categories.find(obj2 => obj2._id === obj1._id);
                                if (matchingObj2) {
                                  return {
                                    matchingObj2                             
                                  };
                                } else {
                                  return null;
                                }
                              }).filter(obj => obj !== null);
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample output

Comment: I added the picture. its just matching the ID but  embedding the same data which is in categories object

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation -

- define `count` and `categories` arrays to be merged
- create a Map of `_id => count`, call it `countIndex`
- `map` the `categories` performing a lookup of id

  - if the id is found, merge the category with the count data
  - otherwise merge the category with the empty count, `{count: 0}`

```js
const mydata = {
  count: [
    { _id: 1, count: 100 },
    { _id: 2, count: 200 },
    { _id: 3, count: 300 },
    { _id: null, count: 400 },
  ],
  categories: [
    { _id: 3, name: "hats" },
    { _id: 1, name: "shoes" },
    { _id: 2, name: "coats" },
    { _id: 9, name: "pants" },
  ],
}

const { count, categories } = mydata

const countIndex = new Map(count.map(c => [c._id, c]))

const result = categories.map(c => {
  if (countIndex.has(c._id))
    return { ...c, ...countIndex.get(c._id) }
  else
    return { ...c, count: 0 }
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top; 0 }
```

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "hats",
    "count": 300
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "shoes",
    "count": 100
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "coats",
    "count": 200
  },
  {
    "_id": 9,
    "name": "pants",
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: but it still not getting the required data.

Comment: and the approached you used is also out of my league lol.

Comment: i've update the answer to include a minimal, verifiable example. can you explain where you are confused? it's similar to your approach with the exception of building a Map first to avoid `find` inside the loop.